# How to call global function from another js file in angular js controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to create a angular file that contains common function and i want to call them in my another angular javascript file globally,

```js
//code in first.js file
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.service("myservice", function () {
    return {
        func1: function () { alert("function in another file") }
    };
});

//code in second.js
/// <reference path="first.js" />

var SocMaster = angular.module("SocietyApp", []);
SocMaster.controller("MsSocietyCntrl", function ($scope, $http,myservice) { 
    $scope.callFoo = function () {
        myservice.func1();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you need to add `myapp` as dependent module in `SocietyApp` like :
`var SocMaster = angular.module("SocietyApp", ['myapp']);` 
And i guess 'comcontrl' should be service not controller.

Comment: Dear rahul i have made some changes in snippet and make renamed comcntrl to myservice and make it service as you said

Comment: please refer my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please refer below code and run it

Check how i have added dependency of `myApp` in `SocietyApp` module

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.service("myservice", function () {
     this.func1= function () { alert("function in another file")        }
 });

//code in second.js
/// <reference path="first.js" />

var SocMaster = angular.module("SocietyApp", ['myapp']);
SocMaster.controller("MsSocietyCntrl", function ($scope, $http,myservice) { 
    $scope.callFoo = function () {
        myservice.func1();
    }
});
```

```html
<html >

  <head>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app='SocietyApp'>
    <div ng-controller='MsSocietyCntrl'>
      <button ng-click="callFoo()">Click</button>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it is working fine when it is in same js file but i want place it another file ie first.js and second.js

Comment: @faisalkhan include reference of both the file in index.html. First file should be of angular module containing `myApp` and after include another file containing module `SocietyApp`

Comment: as im new on this portal can you please guide me where to accept this answer??

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope it will help you.

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.service("myservice", function () {
   this.func1 = function () {
        return alert("function in another file");
    }

});
```